# Uniqueness of expression of a Lie group element

Tags: mathematical-physics, operators, group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

Just take the SU(2) group as an example. The three generators are $J_z$, $J_+$, and $J_-$.

For an element $ g $, sometimes we want to express it as

$$ g = e^{i a J_+} e^{i b J_z} e^{i c J_-} . $$

The problem is, for given $g$, are the parameters $a, b,c $ uniquely determined?

How about a general Lie group?

Comment: in general, the exponential map must not be injective nor surjective. So there might be even no a,b,c that satisfy your condition. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/two-small-facts-about-lie-groups/

Comment: $SU(n)$ contains a circle subgroup $U(1)$. Therefore it's not injective. The choice of $a,b,c,\dots$ is not unique.

Comment: @Marcel: surjectivity as you say is a mysterious and not guaranteed thing, but this is not the reason why analogous parameters might not exist in the general case. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{G}$ be a Lie group of finite dimension $N$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathrm{Lie}(\mathfrak{G})$.

Suppose further that the vectors $\{\hat{X}_j\}_{j=1}^N\subset \mathfrak{g}$ *span* the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (*i.e.* are a $\mathfrak{g}$-basis).

Then there is some neighborhood $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathfrak{G}$ of the identity in $\mathfrak{G}$ such that for every member $\gamma\in\mathcal{N}$ we can find (in general nonunique) $\tau_j\in\mathbb{R}$ *i.e.*

$$\gamma=\prod\limits_{j=1}^N e^{\tau_j\,\hat{X}_j}\tag{1}$$

This is the situation in your question, where $i\,J_z,\,i\,J_\pm$ span $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Indeed there is an open neighborhood $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ of $\mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that the function:

$$\sigma:\mathcal{U}\to\mathcal{N}; \sigma((\tau_j)_{j=1}^N) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^N e^{\tau_j\,\hat{X}_j}\tag{2}$$

is bijective. The $\tau_j$ are then called *canonical co-ordinates of the second kind* for the neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$: they are the unique co-ordinates in the neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$.

Now this does **not** rule out  points $(\tau^\prime_j)_{j=1}^N$ *outside* the neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ such that:

$$\gamma=\prod\limits_{j=1}^N e^{\tau_j\,\hat{X}_j}=\prod\limits_{j=1}^N e^{\tau^\prime_j\,\hat{X}_j}\tag{3}$$

and this explains [Qmechanic's example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/183711/26076) that any $b\in 4\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=0=c$ will give you a product equal to the identity.

It follows from (2) that *every* member of the identity connected component of $\mathfrak{G}$ can be represented as a finite product of the form:

$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^M\,\left(\prod\limits_{j=1}^N e^{\tau_{j\,k}\,\hat{X}_j}\right)\tag{4}$$

*i.e.* an $M$-fold product of the canonical co-ordinate product. In a compact group, there is a strict upper limit, dependent on the exact $\mathfrak{g}$-basis chosen, for $M$, the number of multiplicands needed. In a noncompact group there is no such bound. Thus there are many group members (outside $\mathcal{N}$) in the identity component of $\mathfrak{G}$ which cannot be given canonical co-ordinates and indeed require a bigger product of the form (4). If the group member in question lies *outside* the identity connected component, then no product of the form in (4) will realize it. $SU(2)$, however, is connected (indeed simply connected) so you don't have this problem here. Moreover, in the special case of $SU(2)$ for the special case of the basis $\{J_z,\,J_+,\,J_-\}$ you have chosen, the function defined by (2), with three product members alone, is surjective onto $SU(2)$. It is not, however, injective, as we have already noted with [Qmechanic's example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/183711/26076).

One of the comments stated that the failure of the products (3) and (4) to realize group members was owing to the exponential map's lack of surjectivity. This is not right. In the general Lie group case, there are many group members (outside $\mathcal{N}$) in the identity component of $\mathfrak{G}$ for which there is no solution to (1), as we have noted. This is quite irrespective of whether the exponential is surjective. In a noncompact group, all members of the identity connected component can always be represented by a product of the form (4), its simply that there can be certain elements, say $\zeta$, in the identity component that are not the exponentials of any *lone* Lie algebra member, *i.e.* $\zeta\not\in\exp(\mathfrak{g})$ and there is no $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ such that $e^X=\zeta$.

The exponential map is surjective in $SU(2)$, indeed in $SU(N)$. This is easy to see because all unitary matrices are normal, thus $\gamma\in SU(N)$ unitarily diagonalizable as $\gamma=T\,\exp(i\,\mathrm{diag}(\phi_1,\,\phi_2,\,\cdots))\,T^\dagger$, where $\phi_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and so $X=i\,T\,\mathrm{diag}(\phi_1,\,\phi_2,\,\cdots)\,T^\dagger\in\mathfrak{su}(N)$ is such that $\gamma=e^X$.

The exponential map is surjective for *all compact, connected Lie groups*. As our example shows, though, it is not injective on the whole group, only on a restricted neighborhood of the identity.

The exponential map fails to be surjective on *some* noncompact connected groups: it is surjective for $SE(2)$, the proper 2D Euclidean group (probably for $SE(N)$ as well, but I haven't computed this one) but it fails to be surjective in $SL(2,\,\mathbb{R})$ and $SL(2,\,\mathbb{C})$. the example:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&\alpha\\0&-1\end{array}\right)\in SL(2,\,\mathbb{R})\subset SL(2,\,\mathbb{C})\tag{5}$$

where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is the standard example of a Lie group element which is not the exponential of any element of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\,\mathbb{R})$.

Naturally, $\exp$ is not surjective on any non-connected Lie group (with more than one connected component).

It is still an open question of Lie theory as to what the exact conditions for surjectivity of the exponential are.

Comment: If $X_j$ is a compact generator, the exponent cannot be unique, as the exponential is periodic. Your local uniqueness result only holds if you assume that the coefficients in the exponents are modulo the period, or ar continuous function of the group element.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier That's what the neighborhood $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ was for: as I said, the local uniqueness does not rule out other exponent sets outside $\mathcal{U}$ solving the equation. The co-ordinates are unique *given that they're restricted to $\mathcal{U}$*. I'm sure you'd know that even for noncompact generators one can have the one parameter group returning repeatedly to any given neighborhood of the identity, as in the irrational slope subgroup of the torus, so this will thwart uniqueness of the exponents too.

Comment: But you say in the sentence ending with (1): ''defined by unique $\tau_j\in R$''. It is this statement that is incorrect as stated. The neighborhood is introduced only later in the proof ''Indeed...'', but it should be in the claim!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier You're right. I hit the page with the word unique too early! Many thanks for proofreading!

Answer (score 3):

The exponentials in your factorization are uniquely determined if they exist, but not the exponents themselves.

For related factorizations in general Lie groups see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_decompositions .

Answer (score 2):

Comment to the question (v1): No, such decomposition is in general not unique. E.g. the unit element  ${\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\in SU(2)$ can be written with parameters $b\in 4\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=0=c$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is often the case that calculations simplify when the range of parameters is such that some elements are not uniquely represented.  A necessary condition for the parametrization to be unique is that the integration over the range of parameters produce the volume of the group (the volume is not always known accurately.)